# jQuery Fixed position scroll flicker fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://designobvio.us/DoUs/directPro.html

jQuery Script

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('#nav').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

HTML

```
<nav id="nav" class="grid_2">    
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>↗</span>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul class="secondaryUL">
           <li><a href="#">business</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">skills</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
 </ul>    
</nav>
```

any clue on how to fix the flicker in IE and Chrome.. It looks fine in FF, dont even have Safari to test on.
http://designobvio.us/DoUs/directPro.html

I'm useing jQuery so I dont have to adjust all my css to do this one tweak.  anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this effiencently and symantically clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no way it can be done satisfactorily in javascript. You'll always get a flicker in most browsers.
What i did the last time i tried it, was using `position:fixed.`

Answer (score 1):

Try using animate. Maybe that will help.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#nav').animate({top: $(this).scrollTop()}, 100);
});
```

I haven't tested this, so it may or may not work. I set the duration to 100, but you may also want to play with the duration to get a smoother affect.

Comment: This actually worked so much better(in chrome) but then broke in the rest of the browsers(which orginally worked). If there was a way to control the distance at which the slider travelled I believe this would do the trick. Alas I'm very new to jquery; even this script was taken from another stackoverflow lol. Thanks for your help –